# Can jade Iteration have a Micro-Templating variable?

Tags: node.js, pug, templating

Am using jade as express.js view engin, and I use Micro-Templating ; here is a problem i came across
here is the template

```
 script(id='form',type='text/html')
    select(id='select_category',name='product_category')
       option <%= option%>
```

to use the template

```
$(tmpl('form',{'option':'something'}))
```

now i have more than one option so this is what i did

i change the template

```
 script(id='form',type='text/html')
    select(id='select_category',name='product_category')
       each val,key in  <%= option%>
           option <%= val%>
```

using

```
 $(tmpl('form',{'option':[some arr]}))
```

this will cause a error says "Unexpected token < ";

so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
option #{val}
```

is what you want to put the value of `val` inside your `option` element. Jade uses interpolation syntax similar to ruby/coffeescript.

It's unclear what your desired output is, but if you want those literal PHP-style tags, try:

```
option= '<%=' + val + '%>'
```

Comment: no it wont work still cause the "Unexpected token < " error, i think its because you can put the <%= option%> in jade Iteration